# dompdf placing same font in full bodytag

Tags: php, dompdf, google-webfonts

I have installed tangerine in my dompdf. Now what is happening is when i try on my windows machine it works fine. But in ubuntu when i put the same code in xampp the generated pdf is massed up. I used the tangerine font with only my h3 tags but in the generated pdf the font style is placed in whole body. Here is my dompdf settings

```
<?php
// Include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// Instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf(array('isPhpEnabled' => true));

// Load content from html file
ob_start();
include_once 'pdfcontent.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
$dompdf->loadHtml($output);

//$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('b4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview)
$dompdf->stream("funeral",array("Attachment"=>0));
?>
```

Comment: have you thought about switching to `wkhtmltopdf`? The main difference is that it doesn't try to emulate a browser rendering engine but instead really just is the webkit engine as in chrome's print function.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your PHP. A sample of the HTML would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well the the problem was basically with the cached dompdf file. I have deleted the dompdf folder and uploaded again. Now it works fine.